# Is casting necessary for string columns which contain Int value for doing arithmetic comparison?

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I am using Apache Spark 2.1.1.

I have a Dataset  as follows.

```
final case class TestModel(id: String,
                       code: String, 
                       measure: String, 
                       value: String)
```

I am loading it properly from a csv file. For different `measure` values, the `value` datatype could be different. E.g. if measure is 'Age', then `value` would be age in string. Now to do some processing, I am casting the `value` to IntegerType and then doing the comparison with the age range specified in another dataset.
Is the following correct way to do it ?

```
val testData = spark.read.schema(testSchema).option("header", "false").csv(dataPath).as[TestModel]
val ageBasedTestData = testData.filter($"measure" === "Age")


var ageBasedData = ageBasedTestData.join(anotherDS, ageBasedTestData("code") === anotherDS("code") &&
                               anotherDS("ages").getItem(0) <= ageBasedTestData("value").cast(IntegerType) &&
                               anotherDS("ages").getItem(1) > ageBasedTestData("value").cast(IntegerType))
                               .select( some column names)
```

Is the above casting of `value` column to Interger type before comparison with age range correct way of doing this? Basically I am converting the string to Int just for the comparison purposes then don't care about the datatype. I have ran the code both with the cast and without the cast and both give me same results. So I am not sure what is happening behind the scenes without the cast. Does it automatically cast the string to Int and do the comparison. If it matters, the datatype of "ages" array from anotherDS dataset is Integer.

Comment: I would suggest you to use udf function . just join them and later filter by using udf function

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I think udf functions are discouraged since they cannot be optimized. Also, I don't think udf is necessary for this simple context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I am not sure what is happening behind the scenes without the cast.

Take a look at the execution plan:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT 1 < '42'").explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [unresolvedalias((1 < 42), None)]
+- OneRowRelation$

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
(1 < CAST(42 AS INT)): boolean
Project [(1 < cast(42 as int)) AS (1 < CAST(42 AS INT))#142]
+- OneRowRelation$

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [true AS (1 < CAST(42 AS INT))#142]
+- OneRowRelation$

== Physical Plan ==
*Project [true AS (1 < CAST(42 AS INT))#142]
+- Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

and

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT '42' < 1").explain(true)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [unresolvedalias((42 < 1), None)]
+- OneRowRelation$

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
(CAST(42 AS INT) < 1): boolean
Project [(cast(42 as int) < 1) AS (CAST(42 AS INT) < 1)#147]
+- OneRowRelation$

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [false AS (CAST(42 AS INT) < 1)#147]
+- OneRowRelation$

== Physical Plan ==
*Project [false AS (CAST(42 AS INT) < 1)#147]
+- Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

So if one argument is numeric, the second one will be casted.

**It is still strongly recommended to cast data to desired types** to avoid mistakes like:

```
spark.sql("SELECT '42' < '9'")
```

especially if you consider, that casting rules are tricky and a bit inconsistent:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT to_date('2015-01-01') < '2012-01-01'").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [false AS (CAST(to_date('2015-01-01') AS STRING) < 2012-01-01)#4]
+- Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Let me do this for my case and analyse the results. Then I will accept the answer.

Comment: I analysed the queryExecution plan for both with and without the cast. For with cast, it was properly casting into Int datatype while for without the cast, it was casting into double datatype.