# Pyspark automatic casting behavior

Tags: pyspark

I am learning Pyspark and was confused about behavior that I saw in a tutorial just now. It seems that it is automatically casting in some cases, but I didn't expect that.

The tutorial starts with loading a CSV as follows:

```
departures_df = spark.read.csv('2015-departures.csv.gz', header=True)

departures_df.printSchema()
```

The schema that gets printed is:

```
root
 |-- Date (MM/DD/YYYY): string (nullable = true)
 |-- Flight Number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Destination Airport: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Actual elapsed time (Minutes): string (nullable = true)
```

Note that the fourth column is a string.

The next step in the tutorial runs the filter:

```
departures_df = departures_df.filter(departures_df[3] > 0)
```

I was surprised that this succeeded, because it is comparing a string to a number. I thought that you would need something like the following. The following also succeeds but has exactly the same effect.

```
departures_df = departures_df.filter(departures_df[3].cast(IntegerType()) > 0)
```

So does Pyspark automatically cast in certain situations? What am I missing here?

Comment: You will find this answer useful. It has a predefined casting hierarchy and it will try to do the best match. It is always better to cast your columns and not rely on the automatic behaviour. Always print out the logical plan of the dataframe in case of doubt.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176792/is-casting-necessary-for-string-columns-which-contain-int-value-for-doing-arithm

Comment: also explicit is better than implicit. i'd recommend `departures_df.filter(F.col('Actual elapsed time (Minutes)').cast(IntegerType()) > 0)`